# jQuery event.preventDefault() on submit when form is submitted from jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am building a PHP, AJAX driven comment form.

I have the form set to `preventDefault();` when the form is submitted.

```
$(document).on("submit", "form.comments", function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  //AJAX to submit form
});
```

This works fine.

I just added another function to submit the form when I hit enter:

```
$(document).on("keydown", "textarea[name='comment']", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    $(this).closest("form.comments").submit();
  }
});
```

When I hit enter, it submits the form, but the first function to prevent the submission and submit it with AJAX doesn't kick in.

I know I could just add the AJAX inside the function where it detects the enter key, but I really don't want to do that. Is there any way I can get the current method to work?

Comment: Why on earth would enter in a textarea submit the form, then you can only have one line, and that equals a text input, which submits the form by default when enter is hit. You're reinventing the wheel bigtime!

Comment: Also note that `form.comments` and `form.add-comment` is likely not the same form ?

Comment: You just used this comment form did you not?

Comment: And no, I'll change that. That was just for the example.

Comment: But this textarea supports newlines, just press shift when hitting enter. It also supports markdown and a lot of other things.

Comment: And now you suddenly have one selector matching classes and one that uses name, it's still not the same ?

Comment: Yeah, that's the plan. This is not the finished product. Once I get this figured out the next thing is the get shift+enter = newline to work.

Comment: `textarea[name="comment"]` vs `form.comment`

The damn thing works! It just won't prevent the submission.

Comment: And what browser are you using ?

Comment: Doesn't work in either Chrome or Safari. I'm not sure you understand the issue.

Comment: I was asking as your code wouldn't work in Firefox, an answer was added after my comment, outlining that issue.

Comment: Testing it, it works just fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/Dfab8/

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. It must be an issue elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Alright, I found it. I had not included `event` in the function parameter. I've never had to before. How exactly does that work?

Comment: It's an argument, that's how it works, but in IE the event object is global, so it works without specifying the event argument, and Chrome did the same thing to make it backwards compatible, so it should generally work without the argument, except in Firefox, which does not have a global event object. It's always good practice to specify the event argument anyway.

Comment: Okay cool, for some reason it didn't work in Chrome or Safari, but perhaps it was because I was calling the submit from the script.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The event object isn't exposed to window object in some browsers (*Firefox*), which might be the reason.

Try this:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form.comments", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //AJAX to submit form
})
```

;

Comment: That was not the case. As I said, it works fine. If you hit the submit button. Hit the submit button, it prevents submission and does what it needs to do.
Where I'm running into a problem is preventing the submission when I call it to submit from jQuery and not the HTML document.

Comment: It seems it was the case only when I used event and not just e. What exactly is this parameter?

Comment: it is same as `event`, but cross-browser